# How to copy or restore OS via apt package-list?

Tags: debian, virtualbox, backup

I want to find a way to backup my system in the manner of storing a list installed packages. I want to be able to reproduce my setup for the case of a reinstall or automatically provision a VM with nearly the same software installed.

So I found out that its possible to export a list via dpkg by

```
dpkg --get-selections >/backup/package-selections
```

and than using it on target machine with

```
dpkg --set-selections </backup/package-selections
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Unfortunately this wont work since the list will also contain information of packages I dont want to (re-)install (e.g. kernel images which are already installed or driver for a Nvidia card but target machine has a ATI).

So now Im wondering if there is a smart way to filter the list or decide while exportin or later while importing between necessary packages or not or between low-level-/system-packages and tools or something.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why not just backup everything? The system files won't take much space, and it'll save you a lot of time when you've got to restore. http://www.taobackup.com/coverage.html

Comment: see also http://clonezilla.org/